# Push notifications if app is closed (React-Native)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, react-native

I'm developing React-native app (iOS & Android).
Server connected through web-socket. Server sends notifications about some specific events. App suppose to notify user (using alerts). What if I need to notify user even if app is running in background or closed - how can i do that? Push notifications with [this library](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) will help in cases when app is in background, right? But it will not work if app is closed? So, how can i notify user if app is in background or closed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The library you referenced will indeed allow you to notify users even if the app is closed as it utilised **Push Notifications**. These are delivered to your users' devices no matter the state of your app.

When a user opens a push notification they are taken to your app. [This Push Notifications tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) is a good introduction to the system.

Answer (score -19):

Create your apps with run as background using worker, and check every 1 second, I always use it.

Comment: This is like the opposite of push notification. Also you are unnecessarily draining battery like this.

Comment: so. do you have any method ?

Comment: This is absolutely what you DO NOT want to do. This is why battery drain exists, SMH.

Comment: This should be the correct answer if question was: Why your app runs with low performance.