# react native alarm Notification not working when we close the app

Tags: react-native, alarm

when i set the alarm its working when app is open when i schedule the alarm and close the app its not working. I try on physical devices Android 11 but its not working.

Android Mainfiest code

```
 <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <service android:name="com.emekalites.react.alarm.notification.ANService" android:enabled="true"/>
  <receiver
        android:name="com.emekalites.react.alarm.notification.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_DISMISS" />
            <action android:name="ACTION_SNOOZE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.emekalites.react.alarm.notification.AlarmDismissReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.emekalites.react.alarm.notification.AlarmBootReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Schedule alarm

```
const alarmNotifData = {
      title: 'Alarm Ringing', // Required
      message: this.state.name, // Required
      channel: 'alarm-channel', // Required. Same id as specified in MainApplication's onCreate method
      ticker: 'My Notification Ticker',
      auto_cancel: true, // default: true
      vibrate: true,
      vibration: 100, // default: 100, no vibration if vibrate: false
      small_icon: 'ic_launcher', // Required
      large_icon: 'ic_launcher',
      play_sound: true,
      sound_name: null, // Plays custom notification ringtone if sound_name: null
      color: 'red',
      schedule_once: true, // Works with ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm so alarm fires once
      // tag: 'some_tag',
    };
    var alarm_id;
    if (!isother) {
      try {
        alarm_id = await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm({ ...alarmNotifData, fire_date: fireDate });
        
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error)

      }
```

when i set the alarm its working when app is open when i schedule the alarm and close the app its not working

package.js

```
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.2.2",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.2.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
"install": "^0.13.0",
"npm": "^8.3.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"react-native-alarm-notification": "^1.8.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I was read when you want show if app closed , you have to call that in background app refresh in android , you have to set `push notification` and this show even app closed , for android  you can use `firebase push notification` and for ios basically use `Apns` or `firebase` too. for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767307/push-notifications-if-app-is-closed-react-native)

Comment: You mean that i reschedule the alarm on background resfresh. Its working fine on Android 8 but not in Android 9 and newer. Did you have any example of this